# Get a document with find_one (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bottle

I got a documentstructure like this:

```
{
    "_id": "106.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "maxAge": 48,
    "origin": "some_origin",
    "time": "2016-07-04 11:41:47"
}
```

_id contains an IP-Adress which i want to get with the find_one function of pymongo. 
I am calling it like this:

```
return (self.posts.find_one({"_id": ip}))
```

All it returns is "none" since it is not finding the document. Any Ideas?

Edit: 
I also tried to call it like:

```
return (self.posts.find_one({"_id": str(ip)}))
```

Further Information: 
I got a database called "vpn_service" running in a docker container. 
The collection is alos named "vpn_service".

First i tried to init the Mongoclient like this:

```
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.client = MongoClient(host=host, port=port)
    self.db = self.client.vpn_service
    self.posts = self.db.posts
```

I also tried this:

```
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.client = MongoClient(host=host, port=port)
    self.db = self.client.vpn_service
    self.collection = self.db.vpn_service
    self.posts = self.collection.posts
```

Since just posts.find_one() doesn't find anything either it's probably a problem with the connection.

Comment: This is the result of your 2 versions of connection code:
> Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'vpn_service'), u'posts')
> Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'vpn_service'), u'vpn_service.posts') 

That means, the second is wrong since you are querying the 'vpn_service.posts' collection inside 'vpn_service' db, not the 'posts' collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means it cannot find the document.

Be sure that the document exist and you are querying on the correct type - string.

Also test your pymongo connection (change my values with yours):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost')
db_name = 'test_db'
db = client[db_name]
collection_name = 'test_collection'
collection = db[collection_name]
print collection
```

print result:

> Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'test_db'), u'test_collection')

Comment: There definitely is a document with this _id, i copied it out of the collection. I also made sure with str(ip) that it is a string.
Still got "none" as a result.

Comment: Try more tests, using find function, to get all documents. We need more details. From what you you show here, the documents does not exist.  Test in mongo shell, add a dummy document with a dummy IP and search for it.

Comment: Or something must be wrong in your code. Did you test the same query in the mongo shell?

Comment: It's probably an issue with the connection, since i'm not even finding anything without _id (see my edit)

Comment: Please test your connection using my script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your script prints following: 
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['docker.local:32768'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'vpn_service'), 'vpn_service')

Comment: Such a dumb mistake of me. Since i'm pretty new to programming, i followed the tutorial of pymongo and didnt notice that "posts" isn't a function, it's the collection... shame on me. Works now. 
Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that if `ip` is of type string. This might be creating the problem during search. If its not try typecasting it to string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried: 
return (self.posts.find_one({"_id": str(ip)}))
The result is still none

Comment: `str` does not work inside a mongo query, try the conversion before mongo query.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It's probably an issue with the connection, since i'm not even finding anything without _id (see my edit)